# Download |parse pem file aws secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, json

I have placed pem file as a key value on AWS Secret Manager. When I downloaded the pem file it downloaded as following format.

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----EncryptedText==-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY -----`

How can I convert this to correct pem file format?

The following command I have used to download the secret

secrets=`/usr/local/bin/aws secretsmanager  get-secret-value --region us-$region --secret-id SecretName --query "SecretString" --output text`

`echo $secrets | jq '."keyName"'`

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----EncryptedText==-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY -----
```

Comment: What do you expect the "correct pem file format" should look like? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the file to look like:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EncryptedText==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY -----
```

instead of a one line string.

You can use sed to add new lines:

```
sed -i -e 's@ KEY-----@KEY-----\n@' -e 's@-----END@\n-----END@' file.pem
```

-i option modifies the file directly.